# Method of getting a list of all Private members in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, private, private-members

Like the title says, I'd like to be able to get a list of a Typescript class/instance's private members.

I've tried this during testing but I was concerned that I was going to get all members and was not going to be able to tell if a member is private at runtime. Furthermore, I was unsure of how to do the same with static members.

```js
type Constructor<T> = new () => T;

export default function <T> (classX: Constructor<T>) {
    var c = new classX()
    var made = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c);

    for (var i of made) { console.log(i) }
}
```

Comment: *"...was not going to be able to tell if a member is private at runtime..."* No private members are private at runtime with TypeScript's version of private. They're all public. TypeScript's `private` is purely about the type system, not runtime. (Not *answering* because this doesn't answer the question of how to get a list of private members for testing purposes, if you even can.)

Comment: (In contrast, JavaScript's own private, part of the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which is going to be Stage 4 soonish, are really private.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just prepend your methods with private_ and get private members because at runtime all are just properties of an object there are no reflections in js. This can be achieved using [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) in typescript but still, you need to specify the array of private methods.or just create ____privateMembers____ static property which keeps track of this metadata (typically this is what is done in dynamically typed languages like js and python)

Comment: The issue with this is because I am making a package, I don't know what class I am accepting.